# ASP.NET project on Win2K8 for free?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, iis, subdomain

I have recently gotten the task of uploading a few ASP.NET projects to my VPS, which happens to be running Windows Server 2008 R2. One of these projects has to be given a subdomain (I use the server as DNS), and all projects has a MSSQL database, which have to work.

I've heard that IIS Express doesn't support neither databases nor subdomains, so I'm here to ask you guys what else I'm supposed to use, and preferably, how to do so. I'm brand new to hosting this way. I have regular IIS installed (which I've never worked with), as it comes with the OS, but I've been told that won't run databases either.
I'd prefer a free solution. The server is enough money by itself.

Answer (score 0):

**In windows server 2008**
There is IIS 5 in Windows server 2008. You don't have the Express version, you got the "real" version.

Comment: I installed Express first, because I assumed it would be more light-weight and easier to use. I just installed regular IIS yesterday. So yes, I do have Express version.

Comment: Just install the real one from windows features. And it should work.

Comment: But does it support subdomains and MSSQL databases? And if so, how do I set it up?

Comment: It does,here's some information : http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2